# Firebase Analytics connection to BigQuery timeframe

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

I connected my Firebase Project to Google BigQuery in order to access the raw event data, create custom queries and display them in Google DataStudio.

Everything works like a charm.

However, in BigQuery I can only see 2 weeks of data in the database.

I expected that I would have all the data from the first day since I turned on this integration.

I did not find anything about this 2 weeks limitation. Did I miss something in the documentation? Is it possible having in BigQuery not just 2 weeks but all data beginning from the first day of the integration?

[Bigquery event data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfieR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Data from Firebase Analytics starts uploading into BigQuery the day you enable the connection between both.

So the answer is no, you did not miss anything in the documentation and you only have the data from the day you activated it. And there is not way of uploading the historic afterwards.